# standardize time points for each individual

Tags: r

I have a large dataset `dat` like this:

```
SUB  TIME
 1   0.16
 1   0.76
 1   1.15
 1   1.48
 1   2
 1   2.98
 1   3.98
 1   4.96
 1   8.98
 1   12.13
 1   12.73
 2   0.18
 2   0.75
 2   1.16
 2   1.5
 2   2
 2   3.05
 2   3.98
 2   5.01
 2   8.96
 2   12.1
 2   12.7
 2   13.1
 ...
```

I want to standardize the time points for each individual so that everyone starts from 0. The expected output should look like this:

```
SUB TIME
1   0
1   0.6
1   0.99
1   1.32
1   1.84
1   2.82
1   3.82
1   4.8
1   8.82
1   11.97
1   12.57
2   0
2   0.57
2   0.98
2   1.32
2   1.82
2   2.87
2   3.8
2   4.83
2   8.78
2   11.92
2   12.52
2   12.92
...
```

could anyone give some ideas on how to realized this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you look to google/documentation for "r normalize values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to subtract the first value by group (if sorted, minimum value o/w). I would use `ave` for this, which allows you to apply a function by group and return a vector of the same length.

```
tmp <- textConnection("SUB  TIME
 1   0.16
 1   0.76
 1   1.15
 1   1.48
 1   2
 1   2.98
 1   3.98
 1   4.96
 1   8.98
 1   12.13
 1   12.73
 2   0.18
 2   0.75
 2   1.16
 2   1.5
 2   2
 2   3.05
 2   3.98
 2   5.01
 2   8.96
 2   12.1
 2   12.7
 2   13.1")
dat <- read.table(tmp, header=TRUE)
dat$norm1 <- ave(dat$TIME, dat$SUB, FUN=function(x) x - x[1])
dat$norm2 <- ave(dat$TIME, dat$SUB, FUN=function(x) x - min(x))
```

This yields:

```
> head(dat)
  SUB TIME norm1 norm2
1   1 0.16  0.00  0.00
2   1 0.76  0.60  0.60
3   1 1.15  0.99  0.99
4   1 1.48  1.32  1.32
5   1 2.00  1.84  1.84
6   1 2.98  2.82  2.82
```